# Two abstracts in two languages in Elsevier class

Tags: environments, babel, document-classes, elsarticle

I have a problem with putting two abstracts under the title of my article in elsevier class.

I am using this code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt,3p]{elsarticle}


%% \documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%% The amsthm package provides extended theorem environments

%% \biboptions{comma,round}

% \biboptions{}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}
     {\par\vfil\null}
\else
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}
        \end{center}
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\journal{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title of my paper \tnoteref{label1}}
\tnotetext[label1]{}
\author{name and surname}
\address{univeristy address}
\ead{author@mail.com}
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
  abstract in english 
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{abstract}
 abstract in french
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{english}
\textbf{Primary Class : }00
\textbf{Secondary Class} : 000
\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
keyword1, keyword2
%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%%
%% Start line numbering here if you want
%%
% \linenumbers

%% main text
\section{Introduction }
\end{document}
```

How to put the abstracts under the title and author's name in the first page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the definition of an `abstracts` environment, with also a redefinition of `abstract`. This is not really too invasive: if the editors eventually tell you that only one abstract in the main language is needed, just remove the added code (with the environments' definitions) and the abstract you don't want.

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt,3p]{elsarticle}

%% \documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\journal{}

\newenvironment{abstracts}
 {\global\setbox\absbox=\vbox\bgroup
    \hsize=\textwidth
    \linespread{1}\selectfont}
 {\vspace{-\bigskipamount}\egroup}
\renewenvironment{abstract}[1][]
 {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\selectlanguage{#1}\fi
  \noindent\textbf{\abstractname}\par\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces}
 {\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title of my paper \tnoteref{label1}}
\tnotetext[label1]{A note to the title}

\author{name and surname}
\address{university address}
\ead{author@mail.com}

\begin{abstracts}
\begin{abstract}
  Abstract in English 
\end{abstract}
\begin{abstract}[french]
  Resum\'e en fran\c{c}ais
\end{abstract}
\end{abstracts}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
keyword1, keyword2
%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%%
%% Start line numbering here if you want
%%
% \linenumbers

%% main text
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

In my opinion, this should be considered as an addition to `elsarticle`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, egreg! That definitely should be included to the elsevier class;) You just made my article ready to send, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative that might be even less invasive than @egreg's excellent answer. This modifies the `abstract` environment to build onto the existing `\absbox`, obviating the need for the additional `abstracts` environment. Additionally, one would simply have to remove the unwanted `\begin{abstract}`...`\end{abstract}` if only one abstract was needed (the modifications to the `abstract` environment could be left in place).

**Edit:** Based on @egreg's suggestion in the comments, the box building was simplified to a single line.

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\journal{}

%%Addition...patch the abstract environment to allow multiple calls to build onto the existing \absbox
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbox\inabsbox
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\abstract}{\absbox}{\inabsbox}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch abstract}}%save contents to inabsbox
    \patchcmd{\abstract}{\hsize}{\ifdim\wd\absbox>0pt\bigskip\fi\hsize}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \string\abstract for pre-spacing}}%add spacing before this abstract if this is not the first
    \patchcmd{\abstract}{Abstract}{\abstractname}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \string\abstract for \string\abstractname}}
    \apptocmd{\endabstract}{%
        \global\setbox\absbox=\vbox{\unvbox\absbox\unvbox\inabsbox}%combine boxes
        }{}{\@latex@error{Failed to patch \string\endabstract}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title of my paper \tnoteref{label1}}
\tnotetext[label1]{A note to the title}

\author{name and surname}
\address{university address}
\ead{author@mail.com}

\begin{abstract}
  Abstract in English 
\end{abstract}
%
\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{abstract}
  R\'esum\'e en fran\c{c}ais
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{keyword}
keyword1, keyword2
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Why not simply `\global\setbox\absbox=\vbox{\box\absbox\box\inabsbox}`?

Comment: @egreg: Your suggestion works great for simple text. However, one of my own articles has the abstract in a separate file, which is then `\input` into the `abstract` environment. For this situation to work, the content had to be unboxed, which I did in several unnecessary steps. I modified your suggestion (`\box` to `\unvbox`) to simplify things significantly. Thanks!